# How to use ImagePickerController without displaying the Preview window?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode

I am using the imagePickerController to capture images and then save them to the photo library. After I take the picture I get a Preview window with the "Use" and "Retake" buttons. Is there a way going without the display of that Preview window if I suppose that I am going to use the "Use" button all the time?

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 0):

Set UIImagePicker's `allowsEditing` property to NO.

Answer (score 0):

You can't circumvent the preview screen without a hack. If it is necessary to avoid that screen, you can consider using the [`AV Foundation Framework`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html).